# Preferential Select Query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The issue that we are trying to tackle is best shown with the following illustrative example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  colA INT,
  colB  VARCHAR(10),
   
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


CREATE TABLE table_2
(
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  colY INT,
  colZ  VARCHAR(10),
   
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


INSERT INTO table_1(colA, colB) VALUES(1, 'NPD5A6V9EI'), (2, 'ISO4IK42YQ'), (4, 'J12QAN4O42'), (6,'V8YTZFHCU4');

INSERT INTO table_2(colY, colZ) VALUES(3, 'RBUNWLO753'), (4, 'X2BCEY7O8B'), (5, 'BNUS7R4225'), (6, '72NOWCTH5G');
```

We would like to select our result based on the value of `colA` in `table_1` but if that does not return a result , we would like to return our result based on the value of `colY` in `table_2`.  In other words SELECTing from `table_2` is the backup for SELECTing from `table_1`.  The query returns `NULL` only if neither table satisfies the condition.

A pseudo SQL query could be:

```
SELECT colB FROM table_1 where colA = 3 OR SELECT colZ FROM table_2 where colY = 3;
```

The query should return output based on the following I/O table:

```
I    O
=    =
1    NPD5A6V9EI -- From table_1
2    ISO4IK42YQ -- From table_1
3    RBUNWLO753 -- From table_2
4    J12QAN4O42 -- From table_1 (has precedence over table_2 entry) 
5    BNUS7R4225 -- From table_2
6    V8YTZFHCU4 -- From table_1 (has precedence over table_2 entry)
9    NULL
```

---

Kindly suggest solutions that:

1. make use of the latest DB features (for posterity)
2. work with MySQL version `5.6.51` (for our application)

Comment: please don't cross post

Comment: @nbk My experience has been that Stackoverflow and DBA Stackexchange reach different audiences and the solutions suggested are different.

Comment: Still wait if you get an answer, and if that doesn-#t satisfy you go to the other side

Comment: Explain where the last row of the desired output (`9, NULL`) is taken from..

Comment: @Akina since neither table has value of interest 9 (i.e. ColA in table_1 and ColY in table_2), obviously the result returned will be `Empty set` in MySQL parlance.

Comment: I have asked where the value `9` is taken from (source data does not contain this value) - its `NULL` is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT idx.I, COALESCE(table_1.colB, table_2.colZ) AS `O`
FROM ( SELECT colA AS `I`
       FROM table_1
       UNION
       SELECT colY
       FROM table_2 ) idx
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON idx.I = table_1.colA
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON idx.I = table_2.colY
ORDER BY I
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1b4c25750ee16711547e8074cce9fed9

Answer (score 0):

I simply don't kn ow where you get your last row.

also with Myql 8 you can ise the window function ROW_NUMBER

the rest is self explantory, the sorting comes from colA and Col1, when there are the same numbers the second column orderby2 comes and sorts first for the first table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_1
> (
>   id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   colA INT,
>   colB  VARCHAR(10),
>    
>   PRIMARY KEY(id)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE table_2
> (
>   id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   colY INT,
>   colZ  VARCHAR(10),
>    
>   PRIMARY KEY(id)
> );
>
>
> INSERT INTO table_1(colA, colB) VALUES(1, 'NPD5A6V9EI'), (2, 'ISO4IK42YQ'), (4, 'J12QAN4O42'), (6,'V8YTZFHCU4');
>
> INSERT INTO table_2(colY, colZ) VALUES(3, 'RBUNWLO753'), (4, 'X2BCEY7O8B'), (5, 'BNUS7R4225'), (6, '72NOWCTH5G');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @i := @i +1 AS I,
> colB AS O
> FROM
> (SELECT colA as orderby1,colB,1 ordberby2 froM table_1 
> UNION 
> SELECT colY, colZ,2 froM table_2 ) t1,(SELECT @i := 0) t2
> ORDER BY orderby1,ordberby2
> ```
>
> ```
>  I | O         
> -: | :---------
>  1 | NPD5A6V9EI
>  2 | ISO4IK42YQ
>  3 | RBUNWLO753
>  4 | J12QAN4O42
>  5 | X2BCEY7O8B
>  6 | BNUS7R4225
>  7 | V8YTZFHCU4
>  8 | 72NOWCTH5G
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8c98581f8f6cbc273613f990be91d492)*